# how to provide another control value accessor?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-di

I've already got a directive what is implementing the `ControlValueAccessor` interface (directive's selector is `input[type=date]`) and I need to have another directive implementing `ControlValueAccessor` with selector `input[type=date][datepicker]` - let's call it the datepicker directive.

As you can see the selectors of those directives are covering each other and I'm getting following error when I'm using the datepicker directive:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute
```

the error is thrown there: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.x/packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts#L206

so I've got an idea that maybe I could somehow tell angular to provide the datepicker directive when it is possible, but how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply play with the selectors ?

The first would be

```
input[type=date]:not([datepicker])
```

And second one

```
input[type=date][datepicker]
```

Comment: wow, awesome idea, I'll use it for now, but I'm still curious if there is a way for providing control value accessors - at least built-in directives doesn't have such problems yet they selectors are covering each other as in my case

Comment: eg. DefaultValueAccessor (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.x/packages/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts) - there is used the same trick only for `[type=checkbox]` but there is also other accessors eg. for number (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.x/packages/forms/src/directives/number_value_accessor.ts) where such trick seems to be not necessary

Comment: Well I don't know about you, but I see the same selector logic that I've just provided to you in those two !

Comment: not at all, that's true for `DefaultValueAccessor`, which is using `:not([type=checkbox])`, but at the same time it is not using the `:not([type=number])`, yet `NumberValueAccessor` exists, or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh my bad, i see what you mean. Sorry, I can't help you about that, I usually rely on the selectors to avoid conflicts ...